# row_number reset

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table.

**prod, change, date** 
pr1, 'Yes', 2012-01-01 
pr1, 'No' , 2012-02-01 
pr1, 'No' , 2012-03-01 
pr1, 'Yes', 2012-04-01 
pr1, 'Yes', 2012-05-01 
pr1, 'No' , 2012-06-01

I am trying to build a qry and use row_number() function in order to number rows. Just I need row_number() to reset each time change column has value yes. Then row_number() calculation has to start from beginning. Like this

**prod, change, date, row_number** 
pr1, 'Yes', 2012-01-01, **1** 
pr1, 'No' , 2012-02-01, **2** 
pr1, 'No' , 2012-03-01, **3** 
pr1, 'Yes', 2012-04-01, **1** 
pr1, 'Yes', 2012-05-01, **1** 
pr1, 'No' , 2012-06-01, **2** 
... etc

is there a possibility to do something like that using only SQL? I was looking at window functions like  row_number() over (order by date, prd_prod, change) but it does not work like that. are there any other options?

Comment: SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY date DESC) maybe this will help u? Try by removing DESC too;)

Answer (score 3):

In order to reset the row_number, you have to add "PARTITION BY"

Before:

```
select RowOrder=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY WidgetTimeCreated)
```

After:

```
select RowOrder=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY WidgetType ORDER BY WidgetTimeCreated)
```

Comment: Even if you update the column names your answer will not be correct in this form. Yes, he needs to partition the table to "reset" `row_number()`, but in another way.

Comment: The solution I posted may be helpful to others with a similar but not exact same issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
select *, row_number() over (partition by prod, 
                                (case when change = 'No' then (select max(date) from [<YourTable>] where prod = d.prod and change = 'Yes' and date < d.date)
                                      else date end) order by date) as rownum
from [<YourTable>] d
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
with yes as
(select y.*, row_number() over (partition by prod order by date) yesn
 from mytable y
 where change = 'Yes'),
yesrange as
(select c.*, n.[date] next_date
 from yes c
 left join yes n on c.prod = n.prod and c.yesn+1 = n.yesn)
select m.*, row_number() over (partition by m.prod, r.yesn order by m.date)
from mytable m
join yesrange r 
  on m.prod = r.prod and 
     m.[date] >= r.date and
     m.[date] < coalesce(r.next_date, dateadd(d, 1, m.[date]) )
```

(SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0c522/2))